# show input box when select 5+ from dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

I have a drop-down on Cart page from 1 to 5+. When I select from 1 to 4, Qty is updated along with the price.

When I select 5+ from Dropdown, dropdown should hide and input text-box should be displayed.

Also, I do not want to reload Cart page onChange event of drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

**Html:**

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="text">1</option>
  <option value="text">2</option>
  <option value="text">3</option>
  <option value="text">4</option>
  <option value="text">5</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="text input" style="display:none;">
```

**Js:**

```
$( "#dropdown" ).on( "change", function() {
  var val = $('#dropdown option:selected').text();
  $('#input').hide();
  if(val >= '5'){   
    $('input').show();
    $("#dropdown").hide('slow');
  }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4xqdys6x/)